# Does there exist a constructible (by unmarked straightedge and compass) angle that cannot be quintsected?

Tags: geometry

I know that for example an angle of $20^\circ$ cannot be quintsected because an angle of $4^\circ$ cannot be constructed (I'm thinking in terms of (unmarked) straightedge and compass.  But an angle of $20^\circ$ cannot be constructed  (as above) and I would be interested to see an example of a constructible angle that cannot be quintsected, assuming one exists.

Comment: What about $60^\circ$?

Comment: @Berci quintsection of $60^\circ$ is constructible because $12^\circ=72^\circ-60^\circ$ and $72^\circ$ and $60^\circ$ is constructible.

Answer (score 7):

The $72$ degree angle is constructible but the $\dfrac{72}{5}$ degree angle cannot be.

This follows from the nice theorem that a regular polygon of $n\ge 3$ sides can be constructed by straight edge and compass if and only if $n$ is of the shape
$$2^e p_1p_2\cdots p_k,$$
where the $p_i$ are **distinct** Fermat primes.

Comment: You is too quick for me, dude.

Comment: Thank you Andre'--yes that answers my question.  But how about if we were to require that the resulting angle that can be constructed (after quintsecting) is a whole number degree angle?

Comment: There is **no** integer $k$ such that the $k$-degree angle is not constructible, while the $5k$ degree angle is. This is basically because $180$ is not divisible by $5^2$. We get a whole degree example for trisection because $3^2$ divides $180$.

Comment: Thanks again Andre' for your quick response. I realized this soon after I asked the question, though the way I think of it is that an angle is constructible if and only it is a multiple of 3, and unlike trisecting, quintsecting doesn't give us the multiple of 3 that we would need.  Can you tell me something about the case if we use a marked ruler--such as what is the criteria for being able to construct angles?  And how about using both  marked ruler and compass?  And what about criteria for quintsecting angles (whole number and general) for marked ruler, and marked ruler and compass? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I remember the marked ruler stuff for trisecting, but not for  quinquisecting.  There is a nice algebraic characterization of the numbers constructible by marked straightedge and compass. I forget the name of the book that does these things nicely, it is yellow.

Comment: Actually as far as I know, the exact algebraic characterization of numbers constructible by marked straightedge and compass is not known.  What I believe is known is that "if" a number is constructible by marked ruler and compass then it is in a 2-3-5-6 extension, meaning it consists of a series of extensions of these possible degrees; but we don't know anything about the converse.  Perhaps you're thinking of Martin's (yellow) Geometric Constructions book--he talks about marked ruler constructions, but not marked ruler and compass constructions.

Comment: @ElliotBenjamin: Thanks, right yellow book. My memory of the field was then incorrect.

Comment: Andre', it turns out that your 72 degree angle cannot be quintsected even with a marked ruler, by Pierpont's Theorem, which is in the Martin book--page 140--and generalizes the Fermat prime theorem to Pierpont primes involving powers of both 2 and 3. But then this leads to the question of can a 72 degree angle be quintsected with both a marked ruler and compass? Would you know perhaps how to determine if cos(72/5 degrees) is algebraic over the rationals, and if so, what is the degree of its minimal polymial? If the degree were 7 it would not be constructible by marked ruler and compass.

Comment: @ElliotBenjamin: It is certainly an algebraic number, $\cos(\pi r)$ is algebraic for any rational $r$. Degree I do not see immediately. There is software that might do it, for example Pari.

Comment: Thanks Andre'. I used Pari about 10 years ago, but getting current on it now is not something I want to do (my tech motivation is quite limited). But if you ever feel the inclination to check into this further, I think it could be very interesting, as I believe it is not known whether or not every angle can be quintsected by marked ruler and compass--and I would certainly be very interested to know if you come up with anything.

Comment: I am not satisfied about the answer of whole number degree possible