# quintsect an angle with a compass and a straight edge

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

I require to construct a reasonably accurate $9^{\circ}$. And quickly. I learn that the quickest way is to make a straight line of $180^{\circ}$, bisect it (to make $90^{\circ}$), bisect that angle (to create a $45^{\circ}$ angle), and 5-sect* it.

Using a straight edge and a compass, how would I do this accurately? I need the error margin to be below 0.01%.

Additionally, I need ***proof***.

It is on paper, and my pencil is as sharp as possible.

> *For extra brownie points, tell me the technical word for 5-secting an angle.

Edit: @kennytm got the brownie points !!

Comment: I'd rather construct a pentagon and then bisect three times one of its angles.

Comment: Why do you need accuracy? Are you doing this on paper? Are you making something from wood? How sharp is your pencil?

Comment: 2 -> bisect, 3 -> trisect, 4 -> quadrisect, 5 -> quintsect.

Comment: The title said (marked?) "ruler" and "straightedge", and the content said "compass" and "straightedge". What exactly are the tools you can use?

Comment: @kennytm , it is just a typo

Comment: @Aretino , what do you mean????

Comment: A pentagon (which is constructable) has an angle of 108.  It's supplimetal angle is 72.  Bisect three times to get 72/8 = 9.  I don't know if you can 5-sect an angle in general.  I always sort of assumed you couldn't

Comment: You can't quintsect in general http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/294872/does-there-exist-a-constructible-by-unmarked-straightedge-and-compass-angle-th

Answer (score 1):

You do not quintisect any angles (which is impossible with unmarked straightedge and compasses and an open problem if you have a *marked* straightedge). Instead, use a more ingenious linear combination.

Study Ptolemy's construction of the regular pentagon given [here](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/pentagon.shtml). (This link is also the source of the illustration given below.)

[image]

Once you have constructed the pentagon (or just the needed parts to do the steps below), you then have various ways to render the $9°$ angle. Two are given below:

- Angle $PCQ$ measures $36°$ and is bisected by diameter $CD$. Either bisect one of the resulting half-angles or subtract the full angle $PCQ$ from $45°$.
- Draw chord $BC$. This makes a $45°$ angle with diameter $CD$, and the side from $C$ to the unlabeled vertex on the right makes a $54°$ angle with that diameter. The $9°$ angle is the difference between these two angles.